# Sideload Office Add-ins on Mac for testing

Tags: excel, office-addins

I am currently having trouble adding a personal add-in onto excel.

Following this documentation:
https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac

Under the section "Sideload an add-in on Office for Mac", I create the wef file like it says, however my add-in did not get loaded.

Where can I add my manifest xml file to see that add-in appear in excel?

Comment: For me, it was a problem with the XML file.  It validated OK in an xml tool, but the add-in did not load.  We discovered the error by reverting every change one by one back to the original sample file.

Comment: Even 3 years later, the MS validation tool misses stuff that breaks sideloading.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issues on a Mac running High Sierra ver 10.13.1.
This path was used to save the manifest file. Create missing folders. Just substitute your account name for <user-account>

```
/Users/<user-account>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/documents/wef
```

Restart Excel and choose Insert and select Add-ins and select the down arrow to select the add-in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Local Add-in is not showing up. UI has changed in the last 6 years but now a dialog box opens and says "No Add-ins"